# search google from terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal

How to add search google in my terminal?

Same like this picture. I'm using ubuntu 12.04.

[image]

Comment: Take a look at http://superuser.com/questions/47192/google-search-from-linux-terminal

Comment: It's just a bash script - not a context menu entry, as requested.

Comment: @Mitch Thanks but i just need same as in the pic. It's not easy to use that script

Answer (score 1):

Open Ubuntu Tweak, go to “Source Center”, enable “Google Terminal with Google search support”,  Click “Refresh”. You can get it so easily!

[image: google]

If you are interested in the code, you can visit here: https://code.launchpad.net/~tualatrix/ibentu/gnome-terminal

Comment: I don't have source center in my Ubuntu tweak

Comment: Ubuntu Tweak 0.8 introduced: the “Apps”, combination of App Center & Source Center.